# Count the numbers in a range in which the sum of the odds digits have the same parity of the evens one

Tags: python, performance, integer, interval

As already written in the title I want to count the numbers in the  range (x+1, y) where x and y are integers, in which the sum of the digits in odd places have the same parity of the ones in even places.
I made this code:

```
def findIntegers(x, y):
    count = 0    
    for k in range(int(x)+1, int(y)+1):
        odd_sum = 0
        even_sum = 0
        k = str(k)
        odd_sum += sum([int(k[i]) for i in range(1, len(k), 2) if i % 2 == 1])
        even_sum += sum([int(k[i]) for i in range(0, len(k), 2) if i % 2 == 0])
        if (odd_sum % 2) == (even_sum % 2):
            count += 1            
    return count
```

The code works but for very big range it's very slow. How can I improve my code?

Comment: And clarify the task; is x excluded from the range and y included?

Comment: "even places have same parity as odd places" reduces to very simple rule: the mod 2 sum of **all** the digits equals 0. No need to break it into two pieces. Also, if you just look at some example ranges you'll notice a very simple pattern to the count, so you don't need to actually run through the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First some code simplifications and other adjustments. (1) Your sum
calculations don't need the conditional tests, because the ranges already
ensure compliance. (2) They also don't need to be wrapped in a `[]`. (3)
Even better, if you switch from ranges to slices, you don't need to loop with
in the sum calculations: just give a slice directly to `sum()`. In order to do
that, you can perform string-to-int conversion in one place, before summing.
(4) Because `bool` is a subclass of `int`, your count-incrementing code does
not require conditional logic. (5) This function is difficult to describe and
name compactly, but your current name is especially vague. Here's a possible
renaming. (6) Finally, and this is done purely to simplify the rest of the
discussion, I have modified the function to do the counting over an inclusive
range.

```
def n_parity_balanced_integers(x, y):
    count = 0
    for number in range(x, y + 1):
        digits = tuple(map(int, str(number)))
        count += sum(digits[0::2]) % 2 == sum(digits[1::2]) % 2
    return count
```

Such edits improve the code, but they do not significantly affect the
algorithm's speed. It's still a brute-force solution. The key to making further
progress is to find a pattern that can be used to radically reduce the needed
computation. One way to find these patterns is to experiment with the data. For
example:

```
# A brief experiment.
checks = [
    (0, 9),
    (0, 99),
    (0, 999),
    (0, 9999),
    (10, 19),
    (20, 29),
    (10, 39),
]
for lower, upper in checks:
    print(f'{lower}-{upper}:', n_parity_balanced_integers(lower, upper))

# Output
0-9: 5
0-99: 50
0-999: 500
0-9999: 5000
10-19: 5
20-29: 5
10-39: 15
```

In other words, over any inclusive range spanning an entire power-of-ten's
worth of numbers (or any multiple of that, such as `10-39`), you can instantly
compute the answer without iterating over every discrete number in the range.
So the trick to this problem is to start with the full range, decompose it into
subcomponents that can be computed instantly, and then brute-force any
straggling bits. Give that a shot a see what you come up with.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use type hints and unit tests

They are simple and make your code better.

#### Some improvements and pythonification

`odd_sum` and `even_sum` are initialized with zeroes before adding to them, so you can simply initialize them instead of adding:

```
for k in range(int(x)+1, int(y)+1):
    k = str(k)
    odd_sum = ...
    even_sum = ...
```

`range` with step 2 already omits evens or odds, so the `if` part isn't needed:

```
odd_sum = sum([int(k[i]) for i in range(1, len(k), 2)])
```

Moreover, you don't need the index `i`, you need only digits, so you can use slice instead of `range`:

```
odd_sum = sum(int(digit) for digit in k[1::2])
```

#### Better algorithm

If a number `x` has this property and adding 1 doesn't cause change in other digits except the last, `x+1` will don't have this property, `x+2` will have it once again etc. So among every 10 consecutive numbers staring with ...0 there will be 5 fitting numbers. You should check only starting and ending numbers, the half of the rest will do in any case.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure that this is correct but I don't understand the last sentence `You should check only starting and ending numbers, the half of the rest will do in any case`. Do you mean if `a=10` and`b=100` I should check only a and b or do you mean for every number I should check the starting and the ending digit?

Comment: Only 10 and 100. The answer should be somewhere around (100-10)/2 depending on whether 10 and 100 fit the condition (in fact, it's exactly 45).

Comment: one last question @PavloSlavynskyy, how did you come up to the solution? Is there some related problem?

Comment: Thnx @AJNeufeld, fixed.

2DarkSkull No, just an observation.

Answer (score 1):

By making a few observations an O(1) algorithm can be devised. First note that the statement

> the sum of the digits in odd places have the same parity of the ones
> in even places

is equivalent to the statement that the sum of all the digits equals 0 mod 2. Equivalently, the XOR of the low-order bit of all the digits equals 0. The following function implements this

```py
from typing import Sequence

def is_same_parity(digits: Sequence[int]) -> bool:
    return sum(digits) % 2 == 0
```

The next observation is actually the only important one in term of algorithmic complexity. Every sequence of 10 contiguous integers that starts with a multiple of 10 always has exactly 5 values whose (base 10) digits sum to 0 mod 2. If the first value of the sub sequence `a` (`a mod 10 == 0`) has digits that sum to 0 then the five values are a, a+2, a+4, a+6, and a+8. Otherwise, the values are a+1, a+3,a+5, a+7, and a+9.

We can therefore break our range into three pieces, a beginning piece that goes to the next multiple of 10, a trailing piece that goes from the last multiple of 10 to the end, and a third piece that is everything between the first and last multiple of 10 in the sequence.

The following code implements this idea

```py
def find_integers_helper(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    """
    Counts integers whose base10 digits sum to 0 mod 2 in the range
    x <= z < y
    Break into 3 separate ranges:
        1) x <= z1 < y1, where y1 = 10 * ceiling(x / 10), and
        2) y1 <= z2 < y2, where y2 = 10 * floor(y / 10), and
        3) y2 <= z3 < y
    :param x:
    :param y:
    :return:
    """
    
    y1, y2 = 10 * ceil_div(x, 10), 10 * floor_div(y, 10)
    c1 = sum(1 for z1 in range(x, y1) if is_same_parity(to_digits(z1)))
    c2 = (y2 - y1) // 2
    c3 = sum(1 for z3 in range(y2, y) if is_same_parity(to_digits(z3)))

    return c1 + c2 + c3

# some simple helper functions

def ceil_div(n: int, d: int) -> int:
    return (n + d - 1) // d


def floor_div(n: int, d: int) -> int:
    return n // d


def to_digits(x: int) -> tuple[int]:
    return tuple(int(d) for d in str(x))
```

When I reason about ranges I have a strong preference to think about ranges that look like x <= y < z. It's just the way I've done it my whole life. Your code wants a slightly different range, so your method can call my method with a slight adjustment:

```py
def find_integers(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return find_integers_helper(x + 1, y + 1)
```

Comment: `to_digits` is not defined

Comment: @DarkSkull: Whoops!